# Перехват ошибок из импортированного модуля

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio

Есть модуль PyAudio в котором при запуске, если нет микрофона по переданному индексу устройства `speech_recognition.Microphone(device_index=1)`. Но если данного устройства нет то появляется ошибка - `OSError: [Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels`. Вопрос заключается в том чтобы как-то перехватить эту ошибку в `Try`/`Except`.
Код взят и уменьшен отсюда --> [Видео на YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YeS755SPSI8)

```py
from time import sleep
import speech_recognition as sr
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz


def callback(recognizer, audio):
    pass


try:
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    m = sr.Microphone(device_index=1)
    stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback)
################################################
except OSError:
    print("Микрофон не найден")
#    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#    |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
#          то, что я попробывал
################################################
while True:
    sleep(0.1)
```

Ошибка:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (threaded_listen):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 690, in threaded_listen
    with source as s:
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 138, in __enter__      
    self.audio.open(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код который вы попробовали и который не работает.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, изменил вопрос.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit])

Comment: @gil9red, обновил вопрос.

Comment: Судя по ошибке, Recognizer или Microphone неявно запускают код в потоках и в одном из потоков была та ошибка и не знаю как честно поймать ту ошибку :) Тогда, можно по другому сделать - ввести правильный индекс устройства, вот тут есть пример, что вернет все микрофоны: https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition#the-recognizer-hangs-on-recognizer_instancelisten-specifically-when-its-calling-microphonemicrophonestreamread

Comment: Возьмите код отсюда, сделайте копию у себя и добавьте нужную обработку: https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/73ae57cfc785fc1e01737a53dc70ba2d1491c0c9/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L732

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, не совсем понял что конкретно нужно копировать.

Comment: Скопируйте код из метода `listen_in_background`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка все равно появляется, но теперь ее можно отловить

```py
from time import sleep
import speech_recognition as sr
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz


def callback(recognizer, audio):
    pass

r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone(device_index=1)

try:                                                       <---+++
    with m as source:                                          +++
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)                     +++
    except OSError:                                            +++
            print("Микрофон не обнаружен!!!")              <---+++

stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback)

while True:
    sleep(0.1)
```

```
Микрофон не обнаружен!!!
Exception in thread Thread-1 (threaded_listen):
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
OSError: [Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels
```